# JS array passed into a parameter returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Short question:
I have this function call:
`unlockMaterial('Ore', 0, ['money', 100]);`

I'm trying to pass it into this function:

```
function unlockMaterial (material, index, materialCosts) {
    console.log(material)
    console.log(index)
    console.log(materialCosts)
```

When I run this I get the following into the console:

- Ore
- 0
- undefined (array)

Why is the `materialCosts` array undefined?

BTW in case this helps:
I'm going to use this to call a different function below:

```
function craftItem (material, array) {
    for (var c = 0; c < array.length; c+=2) { 
    /* ... */
```

with the following inside `unlockMaterial`: 
`craftItem(material, materialCosts);`

The actual error rests when I try to grab `array.length` and it says "ERROR: Cannot read property `length` of `undefined`."

Thank you!

EDIT: Here's how the `craftItem` fcn is being called:

```
td4.addEventListener('click', () => {
    craftItem(material, materialCosts);
    });
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://jsfiddle.net/musnbLq4/ To find the bug, post how the function is *actually* being called.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/t4urxup6/

Comment: @Slai just out of curiosity: why?

Comment: @Slai That's not how JavaScript works: https://jsfiddle.net/jwpp255p/

Comment: @CertainPerformance posted

Comment: @JackGoodman This is still not complete... where is `unlockMaterial` in your edit?

Comment: Today I learned you can in fact have an array in javascript with multiple types, because arrays are objects

Comment: @Frish that is completely wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/mm1yf1yg/

Comment: @Frish Maybe so, but I still get the same error if I switch type.

Comment: @Frish Nope, each element in an array can be of a different type. You can have `[42, 'foo', true, [1,2,3], {foo:"bar"}]`... And when you edit your comment, instead of writing **a new comment**, you make us seem like fools!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado let it be known that I am the fool, and that I thought you couldn't have multiple types in a javascript array! < :0)

Comment: @Jack Goodman please post a fiddle in your question.